# Reducing code duplication for const and non const nonmember functions using a template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the two following functions:

```
Thing* find_thing_by_name(const String & name, Map<String,Thing*> & thing_map)
{
    auto it = thing_map.find(name);
    return it->second;
}
const Thing* find_thing_by_name(const String & name, const Map<String,Thing*> & thing_map)
{
    auto it = thing_map.find(name);
    return it->second;
}
```

This is just a simple example for an issue that I want to solve.

The functions have the exact same body, but I need both to handle const and non const versions of my maps. I've seen this issue handled with member functions using a const cast, but these are nonmember functions and I would like to solve this issue using a template. How can I write a templated function that will reduce code duplication? I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: Not directly answering your question but just a suggestion: can you add a member variable to `Thing` such as `m_AllowChange` and depending on whether it is false or true, allow changes to `Thing`. But of course the convenience of this will depend on how complicated the `Thing` class is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

```
template <typename MAP>
auto find_thing_by_name(const String & name, MAP & thing_map)
{
    auto it = thing_map.find(name);
    return it->second;
}
```

then

```
String s = ...;
Map<String,Thing*> nonconst_m = ...;
const Map<String,Thing*> const_m = ...;
find_thing_by_name(s, nonconst_m); // MAP is deduced as Map<String,Thing*>
                                   // thing_map's type is Map<String,Thing*>&
find_thing_by_name(s, const_m);    // MAP is deduced as const Map<String,Thing*>
                                   // thing_map's type is const Map<String,Thing*>&
```

Comment: Wow, is it really that simple? How does the compiler know that the type MAP has a find method?

Comment: @Dillydill123 It depends on you. If you pass something doesn't support that you'll get a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you overthought the issue. The same code in method for both parameter variations (passed through const reference and non const reference) means your code doesn't modify this parameter in method (calls only const methods on it). Or else the same code would not compile for const reference. This means that you should implement only one version of this method, as you could always pass non const thing_map actual parameter in the method with const Map &thing_map formal parameter. 
Also there is no need in your actual example to return const Thing* in the second example, as it->second would still be Thing* not const Thing*.
So this is my sujestion:

```
Thing* find_thing_by_name(const String & name, const Map<String,Thing*> & thing_map)
{
    auto it = thing_map.find(name);
    return it->second;
}
```

or if you would like to restrict access to the Thing object implement only this version:

```
const Thing* find_thing_by_name(const String & name, const Map<String,Thing*> & thing_map)
{
    auto it = thing_map.find(name);
    return it->second;
}
```

then you could use either variant this way:

```
...
const Map<String, Thing *> constMapObj;
const Map<String, Thing *> nonConstMapObj;
....
auto res1 = find_thing_by_name(someKey, constMapObj);
auto res2 = find_thing_by_name(someOtherKey, nonConstMapObj);
```

Comment: You can't overload it like that, the compiler decides on which one to call based on parameters. Your parameters are the same on both overload so this is ambiguous.

Comment: I didn't mean any overload, only one implementation. The answer above is alike, just that parameter is past through non const reference in the symantically const method.